# Writing a Custom Broker about WSO2 CEP

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, broker

I have a question about Custom Broker.

I tried Custom Broker using an example from [this](http://suhothayan.blogspot.jp/2013/02/writing-custom-broker-for-wso2-cep.html?showComment=1378103356515#c6210729634944264553) blog article.
I downloaded a sample template Custom Broker from "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17922825/blog/cep-ext-broker.zip",
I put `cep-broker-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` in `CEP_HOME/repository/components/lib`.

Next, I put `broker.xml` in `CEP_HOME/repository/conf`.
Following contents of `broker.xml`:

```
<brokerTypes xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/broker"><br>
   <brokerType class="org.test.cep.broker.TestBrokerTypeFactory"/><br>
</brokerTypes>
```

And, restart and login to the management console.

But, I accessed Configure -> Broker -> Add on management console, and each time I get the following error messages dumped into Monitor -> System Logs

```
Error during rendering
Error during rendering
IO Error executing tag: JSPException while including path '/CEP/cep_buckets.jsp'. ServletException while including page.
IO Error executing tag: JSPException while including path '/CEP/cep_buckets.jsp'. ServletException while including page.
JSPException while including path '/CEP/cep_buckets.jsp'.
JSPException while including path '/CEP/cep_buckets.jsp'.
Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method getEngineProvidersInfo 
Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method getEngineProvidersInfo 
Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method getEngineProvidersInfo 
Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method getEngineProvidersInfo
```

Also, I get the same error when I access Configure -> Broker -> List, Main -> CEP Buckets -> Add and List.

I use version 2.1.0 of WSO2 CEP.

If I need to explain more, I will add more information later.
I entreat you to help me.

Answer (score 0):

we have checked the pack which is uploaded in the site, Custom Broker component is corrupted in the pack.. We have uploaded the proper working pack again in the site.. Please download the pack again from [1]

[1] http://wso2.com/products/complex-event-processor/

Regards,

Mohan

Comment: I downloaded the pack, custom broker work. Problem solved! Thank you very much!