# What 's the pack on the answer for "Writing a Custom Broker about WSO2 CEP"

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, broker

I have same question for 
[Writing a Custom Broker about WSO2 CEP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596569/writing-a-custom-broker-about-wso2-cep/18620085)

on The Article of the link, Mr.mohanadarshan answerd https://stackoverflow.com/users/2168723/mohanadarshan

But, I can not understand the link of the pack in the answer of the link article.

And I have no times using this Stack Overflow.
So I has no reputation.

Please answer my question.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the [WSO2 Complex Event Processor](http://wso2.com/products/complex-event-processor/) 2.1.0 product again from the WSO2 web site. This is what referred as the 'pack'. Just click on "Binary" link under "Download" section. Make sure that you do not use any download accelerators when downloading.

I hope this helps.